# Can you use array_push() to push an array onto another array?

Tags: php

Is this the correct way of pushing an array into another array? Also, do all array pushes require 2 arguments?

```
$edge = array( "nodeTo" => "$to");
array_push( $node["adjacencies"], $edge);
```

Comment: Yep that's the correct way, assuming `$node['adjacencies']` is an array. Could also do `$node['adjacencies'][] = $edge`

Comment: Do you mean to merge two arrays, or add your array to that array (make it a child)?

Comment: `array_push()` always requires at least 2 args, and doesn't make sense otherwise. But the array append syntax is a lot nicer.  `$array[] = $thing_to_append;`

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `"$to"`, you can just write `$to`.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is quite clear on this:

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function

The function definition lists a two-argument requirement.  You need the pushee and something to push at least.

`array_push` is really designed to be used to push/append multiple elements simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

array_push will add whatever you give it as a new element on the end of the target array.

So your example will add a new array as the last element of $node["adjacencies"] which will be your node connection array.  For your example I believe you would like to use

`$node["adjacencies"] += $edge`

to correctly compose an adjacency map